# DynamoDB: ResourceNotFoundException When Creating Table (local)

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am following the AWS Node.js tutorial, but I cannot get the provided code to work.

Specifically, I am trying to create a “Movies” table on a local instance of DynamoDB and load it with some provided sample data. However, I am receiving `”Cannot do operations on a non-existent table”` when I try to create the table, which seems a bit strange.

For my set up, I am running DynamoDB in one console window. The command I am using and output is as follows:

```
COMPUTERNAME:node-dyna-demo myUserName$ java -Djava.library.path=./dynamodb_local_latest/DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar ./dynamodb_local_latest/DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8000
InMemory:   false
DbPath: null
SharedDb:   true
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams: *
```

In a separate console, I am executing the following code:

```
AWS.config.update({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: ‘testAccessId’,
    secretAccessKey: ‘testAccessKey’
  },
  region: 'us-west-2',
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000'
})

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB()
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

const dbParams = {
  TableName : "Movies",
  KeySchema: [ … ],
  AttributeDefinitions: [ … ],
  ProvisionedThroughput: { … }
}

dynamodb.createTable(dbParams, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(
      'Unable to create table. Error JSON:',
      JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)
    )
  } else {
    console.log(
      'Created table. Table description JSON:',
      JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
    )
  }
})
```

The error I get from execution is:

```
Unable to create table. Error JSON: {
  "message": "Cannot do operations on a non-existent table",
  "code": "ResourceNotFoundException",
  "time": "2018-01-24T15:56:13.229Z",
  "requestId": "c8744331-dd19-4232-bab1-87d03027e7fc",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 9.419252980728942
}
```

Does anyone know a possible cause for this exception?

Answer (score 4):

When Dynamodb local is started without **-sharedDb** flag, there is a possibility for occurrence of this kind of issue.

In your case local dynamodb is started as expected,

java -Djava.library.path=./dynamodb_local_latest/DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar ./dynamodb_local_latest/DynamoDBLocal.jar **-sharedDb**

Try the following solutions,

**Solution 1:**  Remove the credential info in in AWS config

```
AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-west-2',
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000'
})
```

**Reason:** If in case dynamodb local is running without **-sharedDb** flag, it will create new database with respect to that credential.

**Solution 2:** Creating table using the dynamodb shell (http://localhost:8000/shell/#) and verify whether its created or not using the following command

aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000

Comment: It's mentioned in the question that DynamoDB is being started with -SharedDb flag

Answer (score 0):

The first answer gave me a hint for my solution. I am using Java in combination with maven. Hopefully my answer can help others. The AWS region might be conflicting. The Java code points to eu-west-1.

```
amazonDynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
               .standard()
               .withEndpointConfiguration(
                 new AwsClientBuilder
                   .EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:" + 
                       LocalDbCreationRule.port, "eu-west-1"))
               .build();
```

But my AWS config in my home folder on my local machine on location

```
~/.aws/config
```

showed the following:

```
[default]
region = eu-central-1
```

I changed the region to eu-west-1, matching the Java code, in my local config and the issue was resolved.